# Unbuntu is not showing effects of the command line {eval "$(starship init bash)"} in .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

OS: Windows 10

Terminal: Unbuntu, git bash

I tried to load starship shell prompt in ubuntu which is opened from my wezterm terminal simulator. By running `echo $0`, the terminal returns `-bash`. Thus I created a `.bashrc` file right in `\Users\MYNAME`, it has nothing but the line in the end: `eval "$(starship init bash)"`. I tried to delete the line to see if there is any difference. It did not work for Unbuntu, while one thing to notice is it worked on git bash. What should I do to make it work?